# How can I put two tables in two columns within a section, each one with a title?

Tags: tables, columns, pylatex

I'm trying to generate the following pdf:

[image]

for which I'm using the following code:

```
with doc.create(Center()) as centered:

    with centered.create(Section("Reportes de clientes", numbering = False)) as customers:
        with customers.create(Tabu("X[c] X[c]")) as customers_table:

            stock = Subsection(df["df_name"], numbering = False)
            stock.append(NoEscape(final_df.loc[tenant, (df["df_name"])].astype(np.float64).to_latex()))

            movement = Subsection(df1["df_name"], numbering = False)
            movement.append(NoEscape(final_df.loc[tenant, (df1["df_name"])].astype(np.float64).to_latex()))

            customers_table.add_row([stock, movement])
```

The pdf is created but it returns with an error in the log as it follows:

```
! You can't use `\hrule' here except with leaders.
\tabu@verticalspacing ...nalstrut \@gobble \hrule 
                                                  height\@tempdima depth\@te...
l.44 \end{tabu}
               
To put a horizontal rule in an hbox or an alignment,
you should use \leaders or \hrulefill (see The TeXbook).

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   d
l.44 \end{tabu}
               
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   d
l.44 \end{tabu}
               
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)
```

And since it's within a loop it prevents from continuing with the code. I'm new to both pylatex as well as latex, so i'm a bit lost here.

Answer (score 0):

After further testing I finally managed to achieve the goal.
Ended up creating a `Centered` Section with a `Tabular` within as it follows:

```
with doc.create(Center()) as centered:

        with centered.create(Section("Visualización en minutos", numbering = False)) as visualization:
            with visualization.create(Tabular("c c")) as visualization_table:

                visualization_table.add_hline()
                visualization_table.add_empty_row()
                visualization_table.add_row((df2["df_name"], df3["df_name"]))
                visualization_table.add_row((NoEscape(final_df.loc[tenant, (df2["df_name"])].astype(np.float64).to_latex()), NoEscape(final_df.loc[tenant, (df3["df_name"])].astype(np.float64).nlargest(10).to_latex())))
```